# I have used alienForm foerver. Recent my host (ionos) requires SMTP authentication to use it now. What do I need to get it to authrorize?

Tags: perl, smtp, authorization, ionos

```
$smtp_server    = 'smtp.ionos.com';


The perl script I used is AlienForm by jon hedley.
```

Now that ionos requires SMTP Authorization, i have stumped as to how to include it. I am clearly not that savvy with said language.

I've tried...

```
$smtp_server    = 'smtp.ionos.com', 'port' = 25, username = 'username', password = 'password';

$smtp_server    = 'smtp.ionos.com', 'port' = 25, Authusername = 'username', Authpassword = 'password';

$smtp_server    = 'smtp.ionos.com';
$smtp_port    = 25;
$smtp_username    = 'username';
$smtp_password    = 'password';
```

None of that worked. The script itself can be found here...

[http://www.calladorn.com/af.zip`](http://www.calladorn.com/af.zip%60)
and I know the hint to it all based on what ionos said is here...
https://www.calladorn.com/herestheclue.jpg

Comment: The link http://www.calladorn.com/AlienForm.zip does not work. Please include a complete minimal script. See [mcve] for more information

Answer (score 1):

I took a peek at your script ([corrected link](http://www.calladorn.com/af.zip)). It uses [Mail::Sendmail](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::Sendmail) for smtp, which supports a [hashref containing authentication options](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::Sendmail#$mail%7Bauth%7D).

I haven't tested this out but you can try making the following changes:

Comment out the sendmail command per the comments starting on line 23.

```
30  #$mail_cmd       = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
```

Enable SMTP server support on port 25:

```
42  $smtp_server    = 'smtp.ionos.com:25';
```

Add your username/password after line 291

```
291  $mail{smtp} = $smtp_server;
292  $mail{auth} = {
293      user     => 'username@example.com',
294      password => 'hopefullyasecurepassword',
295      required => 1,
296  };
```

You may need to fiddle with some of the authentication options but this should get you started.

Comment: I'll try it out and answer back here